# In python, how to Combine multiple arrays in the same column + row into one array?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe df with a column named pvalues.  Here is the column

```
print(grouped['pvalue'].to_dict())
{0: [array([0.96612999, 0.30348366])]
4: [array([0.66871158, 0.0011381 ]), array([0.18113085, 0.04860657])], 
5: [array([0.66871158, 0.0011381 ]), array([0.00000000e+00, 8.54560803e-07])], 
6: [array([0.66871158, 0.0011381 ]), array([8.47561031e-131, 1.28484156e-018])]}
```

basically I want a function that will keep index 0 the same but will make index 4 look like this:

```
0: [array([0.96612999, 0.30348366])]
4:[array([0.66871158, 0.0011381 ,0.18113085, 0.04860657])]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to use (different outputs):

```
>>> grouped['pvalue'].agg(np.ravel).to_dict()
{0: array([0.96612999, 0.30348366]),
 4: array([0.66871158, 0.0011381 , 0.18113085, 0.04860657]),
 5: array([6.68711580e-01, 1.13810000e-03, 0.00000000e+00, 8.54560803e-07]),
 6: array([6.68711580e-001, 1.13810000e-003, 8.47561031e-131, 1.28484156e-018])}

>>> grouped['pvalue'].agg(lambda x: np.ravel(x)[None]).to_dict()
{0: array([[0.96612999, 0.30348366]]),
 4: array([[0.66871158, 0.0011381 , 0.18113085, 0.04860657]]),
 5: array([[6.68711580e-01, 1.13810000e-03, 0.00000000e+00, 8.54560803e-07]]),
 6: array([[6.68711580e-001, 1.13810000e-003, 8.47561031e-131,
         1.28484156e-018]])}

# What you expect
>>> grouped['pvalue'].agg(lambda x: [np.ravel(x)]).to_dict()
{0: [array([0.96612999, 0.30348366])],
 4: [array([0.66871158, 0.0011381 , 0.18113085, 0.04860657])],
 5: [array([6.68711580e-01, 1.13810000e-03, 0.00000000e+00, 8.54560803e-07])],
 6: [array([6.68711580e-001, 1.13810000e-003, 8.47561031e-131, 1.28484156e-018])]}
```